# Define Method with unknown number of arguments not equal to None

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, arguments

I am working in Python 3.7.

Assume I have these two functions, and I **cannot** change their code (i.e. set default arguments such as `x=None`).

```
def f1(x):
    return x

def f2(x,y):
    return x+y
```

Assume I have a class like this.

```
class test():
    def __init__(self, var1, var2 = None, func):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        self.func = func

    def apply_func(self):
        return self.func(self.var1, self.var2)
```

How do I structure the definition of the class `test`, such that `self.var2`is only passed when `var2 is not None`? Such that I do not get an argument (too many arguments) error if I instantiate with the attribute `fun1` and call the method `apply_func`? Moreover, I do not want to create two different classes for each function type and only method function `apply_func`.

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the argument list according to the function object's `__code__.argcount` attribute, which stores the number of arguments expected by the function:

```
def f1(x):
    return x

def f2(x,y):
    return x+y

class test():
    def __init__(self, func, var1, var2 = None):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        self.func = func

    def apply_func(self):
        return self.func(*(self.var1, self.var2)[:self.func.__code__.co_argcount])
```

so that:

```
print(test(f1, 1).apply_func())
print(test(f2, 1, 2).apply_func())
```

outputs:

```
1
3
```